# Passing the interface of a class throws errors but passing just the class works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes:

DefectsController

```
public abstract class DefectsController<TDefect, TDefectService> :
    ApplicationController<DefectsController<TDefect, TDefectService>, TDefect>
    where TDefectService : IEntityService<TDefect>
    where TDefect : Defect
{
    private readonly TDefectService defectService;


    public DefectsController(TDefectService defectService)
        : base(defectService)
    {
        this.defectService = defectService;
    }
}
```

and JobDefectsController (there are other parts as well, these are just examples)

```
public class JobDefectsController : DefectsController<JobDefect, IEntityService<JobDefect>>
{
    public JobDefectsController(EntityService<JobDefect> service)
        : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

For some reason if I change JobDefectsController's constructor to using IEntityService instead then if I try to access `defectService` in the DefectsController it throws unknown errors.

Edit: This error: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation

There used to be a class called `JobDefectsService` which inherited from `IEntityService<JobDefect>` and the interface of that (`IJobDefectService`) could be used in place of both `IEntityService<JobDefect>` and `EntityService<JobDefect>` without problems.

Anyone have any clue to what the problem could be?

Thanks,
Harold

Comment: What do you mean by "it throws unknown errors"?

Comment: What's this tag soup :-)

Comment: "The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation"

Comment: And it's done in c# with asp.net-mvc (hence the controller and services) and used with fluent-nhibernate (but I wasn't sure if that was involved, I'm only helping on someone else's project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, it was an issue with `IEntityService` not having the function `Query` in it whereas `EntityService` did. I did not realise that these classes were built within the project and now feel like a bit of a fool.

Oh well, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor parameter and your second class parameter need to be the same type. I.e. `TDefectService` .

If you want to use the interface then your concrete class should be defined as follows...

```
public class JobDefectsController : DefectsController<JobDefect, IEntityService<JobDefect>>
{
    public JobDefectsController(IEntityService<JobDefect> service)
        : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

To use the concrete class then you need to do this...

```
public class JobDefectsController : DefectsController<JobDefect, EntityService<JobDefect>>
{
    public JobDefectsController(EntityService<JobDefect> service)
        : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is it works if I used `DefectsController<JobDefect, IEntityService<JobDefect>` and then put `EntityService<JobDefect>` into the constructor, but it won't work any other way

Comment: ApplicationController might have a restriction on TDefectService to say it has to be a class rather than an interface as it may need to new() it up. How is application controller defined?